# Including non-theatrical "Movies"

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Final TV Decision](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220/final-tv-decision)

*Sorry for this "duplicate" post but related discussions are spread throughout meta and the Q&A.*

There has been a lot of discussion circling around including *other* movie productions that are not necessarily "theatrical releases." *Other* scope issues aside, this one seems pretty reasonable. **I tend to agree that "movies" — regardless of the venue or media — should be on topic.** This would include made-for-TV movies, short film, direct-to-DVD movies, and the like.

I don't want to get into a whole semantic argument about what, exactly, a "movie" is, because honestly, the edge cases are just that… edge cases. Suffice it to say "movies" does not include things like music videos, commercials, speculation over who's the namesake in How I Met Your Mother, and who's going to be the next American Idol. Use your best judgement.

What do you say? Should we weave this into the FAQ?